# How to grep only the last 30 days of input from a log file?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, ubuntu, grep

I want to see the all the packages that were upgraded in the last 30 days.

So I run this command:

```
cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep -a -A 2 Upgrade
```

I get this output:

```
...

Upgrade: gcc-8-base:amd64 (8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1, 8.3.0-26ubuntu1~18.04), libgcc1:amd64 (1:8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1, 1:8.3.0-26ubuntu1~18.04), libstdc++6:amd64 (8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1, 8.3.0-26ubuntu1~18.04)
End-Date: 2020-03-24  10:01:31

--
Upgrade: libsasl2-2:amd64 (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2, 2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.1)
End-Date: 2020-03-24  10:01:35

--
Upgrade: libsystemd0:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.33, 237-3ubuntu10.38), libpam-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.33, 237-3ubuntu10.38), systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.33, 237-3ubuntu10.38), libnss-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.33, 237-3ubuntu10.38)
End-Date: 2020-03-24  10:01:43

--
Upgrade: vim-common:amd64 (2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.1, 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3), vim-runtime:amd64 (2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.1, 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3), vim:amd64 (2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.1, 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3), vim-tiny:amd64 (2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.1, 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3)
End-Date: 2020-03-24  10:01:49

--
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.74.76, 4.15.0.91.83), linux-image-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.74.76, 4.15.0.91.83), linux-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.74.76, 4.15.0.91.83)
End-Date: 2020-03-24  10:02:29

--
Upgrade: git:amd64 (1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.5, 1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.7)
End-Date: 2020-04-27  08:31:00

--
Upgrade: git-man:amd64 (1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.5, 1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.7)
End-Date: 2020-04-27  08:31:06

--
Upgrade: python3-apport:amd64 (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.12, 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.14)
End-Date: 2020-04-27  08:31:09

--
Upgrade: python3-problem-report:amd64 (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.12, 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.14)
End-Date: 2020-04-27  08:31:12

--
Upgrade: apport:amd64 (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.12, 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.14)
End-Date: 2020-04-27  08:31:20


...
```

Now I want to grep only the lines that were appended to the file in the last 30 days. And I want it to be relevant to my current time always, so I don't have to change the syntax and dates every time I run the command, so always 30 days. As you can see there are dates in the lines so it should be possible but the syntax is to complex for me.

Comment: IMO, `grep` is the wrong tool for this. I would simply loop over the file and ignore lines as long as you are not yet in the time window your are interested in.

Comment: There is also an ambiguity with `grep -A 2` because sometimes you have a line starting with `Remove:` after the line with `Upgrade:` and before the line starting with `End-Date:`. Do you want your script to grep that line too?

Comment: Second problem. On my system, logged lines from previous monthes are no more archived in `/var/log/apt/history.log`, but in compressed files like `/var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz`, `/var/log/apt/history.log.2.gz`, etc... where the most recent one is `/var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz`. So it would be enough to grep `/var/log/apt/history.log` and `/var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz`.

Comment: I did not know that, I want the upgrade line and its date of upgrade, don't know the syntax to get that 100% of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
$ awk -v d="$(date -d "today -30 days" "+%F %T")"   \
      '(t && $2" "$3 > d){print t;print $0;t=""}
       /Upgrade/{t=$0}' log-file
```

Answer (score 1):

I would adapt the answer of kvantour as follows, for the case that there is an extra line between `Upgrade:` and `End-Date:` (which happens sometimes):

```
awk -v d="$(date -d "today -30 days" "+%F %T")" '
  /^End-Date: /{if (t && $2" "$3 > d) {print t; print $0; t=""}}
  /^Upgrade: / {t=$0}
' /var/log/apt/history.log
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly! Thanks! Now I don't know to which user should I give a green checkmark. Also, how would this look as a single line so I could put it in a crontab?

Comment: Give him the green checkmark and upvote my solution.  This command fits in one line as: `awk -v d="$(date -d "today -30 days" "+%F %T")" '/^End-Date: /{if (t && $2" "$3 > d) {print t; print $0; t=""}}/^Upgrade: / {t=$0}' /var/log/apt/history.log`, but this is as ugly as unreadable. So, I would copy the four lines above into a bash script, and then call that script from the crontab.